# libpam-pwquality not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: pam

I installed `libpam-pwquality`:

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-pwquality
```

And configured `/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3 minlen=10

password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
password        required                        pam_deny.so
password        required                        pam_permit.so
```

Then when I ran `passwd`, I could still set a password of 2 or 3 characters. What was missing?

Comment: What are the other lines? All i find refers to the first line and only this one being set! I also read later configurations overwrite earlier ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the options in pwquality's configuration file, `/etc/security/pwquality.conf`.

Comment: this doesnt work for ubuntu 18.04 - weak passwords are still accepted :(